# How to use arrays of Textures in CUDA

Tags: cuda, gpu

I was trying to use an array of textures in CUDA but I'm getting an "invalid texture reference" error. Anyone has any idea how to implement array of textures?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdio>
#include<cstdlib>

#define MAX_TEXTURE 134217728
#define MAX_LENGTH 268435456

using namespace std;

texture<char, 1, cudaReadModeElementType> texref[2];

int main(){
// host variable
char *text;
// device variable
char *dev_a;

text = (char*)malloc(MAX_LENGTH*sizeof(char));

// any initial value
for(int i=0; i<MAX_LENGTH; i++)
   text[i] = 'a';

cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_a, MAX_LENGTH*sizeof(char));
cudaMemcpy(dev_a, text, MAX_LENGTH*sizeof(char), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

cudaError_t err =  cudaBindTexture(0, texref[0], dev_a, MAX_TEXTURE*sizeof(char));
cout << cudaGetErrorString(err) << endl;

size_t offset = MAX_TEXTURE;
err =  cudaBindTexture(&offset, texref[1], dev_a, MAX_TEXTURE*sizeof(char));
cout << cudaGetErrorString(err) << endl;


cudaFree(dev_a);
free(text);
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is not possible.

If available to you (Kepler or Maxwell gpu and cuda 5.0 or later), you should try [texture objects (bindless textures)](http://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/cuda-pro-tip-kepler-texture-objects-improve-performance-and-flexibility/).

In my code I faked the array by using a function to access various texture references with something similar to the following (in a header file):

```
texture<char, 1, cudaReadModeElementType> tex0;
texture<char, 1, cudaReadModeElementType> tex1;
// ...

texture<char, 1, cudaReadModeElementType> getTexture( int id )
{
    if( id == 0 )
        return tex0;
    else if( id == 1 )
        return tex1;
    // ...
}
```

As far as I know there is no way to avoid listing all the `texture<char, 1, cudaReadModeElementType> texX;` explicitly and be aware that texture references are declared at file scope.

Probably you can improve my code snippet by using preprocessor macros...

Comment: I used that multi variable reference before for that problem, but it makes it so ugly and not flexible (a new variable is required every time a texture references 2^27 elements). I'm using Fermi architecture and I thought it could have a more elegant solution. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, it is ugly. But you can put that code in a header file and you don't need to see it again if you provide a nice way to access them. For example, you can provide a function like `bindNextRef()` that keeps track of which references are already used and other stuff like this...